# PHP AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Cannot post file more than 2GB

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed an application in Elastic Beanstalk, changed some configuration so that I can upload larger files and restart nginx server.
When I upload one file less than 2 GB, it is uploaded successfully. However, when I upload a file more than 2 GB, it does not upload successfully. Below are the lines that I have added in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
client_max_body_size 7500M;
proxy_connect_timeout 1200s;
proxy_send_timeout 1200s;
proxy_read_timeout 1200s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 1200s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 1200s;
```

Also, I have added config file in .ebextensions and put in the following content:

```
files:
    "/etc/php.d/99uploadsize.ini":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            post_max_size = 5000M
            upload_max_filesize = 5000M
            memory_limit = 5000M
commands:
    remove_old_ini:
        command: "rm -f /etc/php.d/99uploadsize.ini.bak"
```

and also tried the following content:

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            post_max_size = 7500M
            upload_max_filesize = 5000M
            memory_limit = 7500M
            client_max_body_size = 5000M
```

Here is the phpinfo() snapshot:

[image]

Where am I going wrong? Kindly assist me

Comment: Why do you need your Nginx server to proxy the upload ?

Comment: Earlier I got 'Entity too Large' due to which added those lines

Comment: We need some more information. Are you sure your EC2 instance size has enough memory, and enough storage? Also, why not just use S3 instead of EB? EB instances are volatile, and storage on the VMs are not persistent.

Comment: @Labu we have incresed the volume of the memroy to 32 GB and we are hosting a server-side script therefore we couldn't host it on S3

Comment: @user1584253 have you checked the section of your phpinfo() that shows the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize were updated correctly? It's possible these values are not being read properly.

Comment: @Hugo Pakula yes, in phpinfo() it shows the correct values of ost_max_size and upload_max_filesize which is 7500M for each.

Comment: @HugoPakula I have set post_max_size and upload_max_size 7500M in /etc/php.ini file manually, do I have to restart anything for this? Also, I have added the content of .ebextensions/change_upload_size.config in the question, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PHP Settings

Your PHP Settings are absolute correct are there is no error is the settings.

## Uploading Error Not PHP

As per you picture posted the Error Code i.e. 7 which means

[UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE - 7; Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

It means you uploading code is correct but at the time of writing the file on the system it is failed.

## Apache Settings

[LimitRequestBody](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)

This directive specifies the number of bytes from 0 (meaning unlimited) to 2147483647 (2GB) that are allowed in a request body.

The LimitRequestBody directive allows the user to set a limit on the allowed size of an HTTP request message body within the context in which the directive is given (server, per-directory, per-file or per-location). If the client request exceeds that limit, the server will return an error response instead of servicing the request. The size of a normal request message body will vary greatly depending on the nature of the resource and the methods allowed on that resource. CGI scripts typically use the message body for retrieving form information. Implementations of the PUT method will require a value at least as large as any representation that the server wishes to accept for that resource.

This directive gives the server administrator greater control over abnormal client request behavior, which may be useful for avoiding some forms of denial-of-service attacks.

## Solution:

You cannot post/upload the file through PHP more than 2 GB as Apache server will not let it do it.

The Only solution through is that you can zip it and while doing zip split the file less then 2 GB per file and then unzip them, to server which each request.

Run the script to unzip the file and do things.